# How to test if a kernel is a valid kernel

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, svm

If I define my own method of determining the similarity between two input entities of my Support Vector Machine classifier, and thus define it as my kernel, how do I verify if it is indeed a valid kernel that I can use?

For example, if my inputs are strings, and the kernel I choose is lets say some kind of a string distance metric, how can I decide if I can use it or not for my SVM. I know there are some conditions for a valid SVM kernel. Can anyone tell me what they are and how does one go about verifying those conditions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Kernel functions must satisfy [Mercer's condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer%27s_condition)  You can also find answers to what you are asking on the  [stats forum](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23386/what-is-a-kernel-and-what-sets-it-apart-from-other-functions).

Comment: Thanks. The link to the other post is very helpful.

Answer (score 10):

The most straight forward test is based on the following:  A kernel function is valid if and only if the kernel matrix for any particular set of data points has all non-negative eigenvalues.  You can easily test this by taking a reasonably large set of data points and simply checking if it is true.  For example, if you selected 2000 data samples at random, created their corresponding 2000x2000 kernel matrix, and observed that it had non-negative eigenvalues, then it is highly likely that you have a legit kernel.  Alternatively, if there are any negative eigenvalues then the candidate kernel function is definitely not a legitimate kernel.

Answer (score 8):

Also a reference you can check out is http://cs.nyu.edu/~dsontag/courses/ml12/slides/lecture6.pdf where author provides "Kernel Algebra" that follows from the statements made above -- Mercer's Theorem that the corresponding Kernel Matrix is symmetric positive semi-definite and the positive eigenvalues follows from that.  The author also shows, as an example, that the Gaussian function makes a valid Kernel.  I will provide it here in case you don't want to look up the reference:
[image: Kernel Algebra & Description of Proof of Gaussian as a valid Kernel]